# Flexbox display issues on mobiles, tablets & old browsers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd love someone to be able to explain this problem. From looking around the internet, surprisingly I cannot actually find a detailed solution or explanation of this problem.

The code I've included shows what appears to be a working display that uses a flex box. Presumably this problem only happens with flex boxes (please correct me if im wrong!). However, if you view this code on an old browser or some phones/tablets, the display is horribly wrong.

I thought adding the webkit rules would resolve the issue, but they appear to do nothing.

1. How can this problem be fixed?
2. Is there somewhere I can see a list of -webkit or -moz rules I need to add to my website for every flex (and others?) rule?

Really appreciate any help here, thanks!

display problem on internet explorer 9:

[image: i.e.9]

display problem on safari on iPad 4:

[image]

```css
#wrap-a {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-evenly;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.the-cta-top, .the-cta-bottom {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
}
.the-cta-top a:link, .the-cta-top a:visited, .the-cta-middle a:link, .the-cta-middle a:visited, .the-cta-bottom a:link, .the-cta-bottom a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #393939;
}
body {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgreen
}
.the-cta {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 150px;min-width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-top: 30px;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    display: inline-flex;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<article id="wrap-a">
            <nav onclick="location.href='#';" class="the-cta">
                <span class="the-cta-top">some</span>
                <span class="the-cta-middle"><a href="#">text</a></span>
                <span class="the-cta-bottom">here</span>
            </nav><!--
            --><nav onclick="location.href='#';" class="the-cta">
                <span class="the-cta-top">more</span>
                <span class="the-cta-middle"><a href="#">text</a></span>
                <span class="the-cta-bottom">here</span>
            </nav>
        </article>
```

Comment: So how does it render different on older browsers? ... In image would be helpful.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: I have no image but the circles display on the left with all the text inside cluttered at the top

Comment: Craig I've already seen that site but it doesn't show any solutions or a list of -webkit or -moz rules to add

Comment: @user8758206 It gives you a list of known issues and workarounds. As a general rule of thumb, I thought that manually creating vendor prefixes was bad? :)

Comment: @CraigvanTonder Nope, nothing wrong with adding prefix manually.

Comment: @user8758206 First, sites like https://caniuse.com/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ provide info which version a browser brand need prefixed CSS properties, which is the best _list_ you will find. Second, the statement _"the circles display on the left with all the text inside cluttered at the top"_ is way to vague. Please provide 2 screen shorts, one working and one not working.

Comment: ok thanks for your comments - I've attached 2 screenshots to this post as an edit to the original question's description. One in i.e.9 and another in safari on the iPad 4. They use the same code as in this example, which results in these display issues

Comment: I see you tested on IE9, and that is not gonna work as it doesn't support Flexbox at all, so do you need to support it?

Comment: I built it on the presumption that if it's not compatible the some of the audience won't be able to see your website properly, so shouldn't all websites be ok for all browsers? Also, what's the use of -wekbit and -moz etc?

Comment: If your audience use IE9, your site should support it, if not, then it is common to redirect users to a page that will look okay, or one telling them they need to upgrade their browser. About prefixes, when new properties is released, they use prefix like `-webkit-`, and this because their definitions, and how they work, often changed before being standardized, hence the need of prefix to enable backward compatibility for older browser versions.

Comment: I also update my answer with a sample that works from IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9 doesn't support Flexbox, so for it you need another solution (added a sample at the end).

When it comes to Safari on iPad4 (your 2nd screenshot), which doesn't space it properly, is caused by the fact that `space-evenly` isn't fully supported on all newer browsers, hence both circles aligns to the left.

In below sample I made use the pseudo elements to create the same effect. Do note though, that this trick using pseudo elements won't work if the items will start wrap.

Stack snippet

```css
#wrap-a {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  /*  space-evenly is not cross browser supported  */
  /*-webkit-justify-content: space-evenly;  */
  /*justify-content: space-evenly;  */

  /* combine space-between with a pseudo to acheive space-evenly  */
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;     /*  added  */
  justify-content: space-between;             /*  added  */

  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;                /*  added  */
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

  /* added pseudo to acheive space-evenly  */
#wrap-a::before, #wrap-a::after {
  content: '';
}

.the-cta-top,
.the-cta-bottom {
  /*display: block;                               not needed  */
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.the-cta-top a:link,
.the-cta-top a:visited,
.the-cta-middle a:link,
.the-cta-middle a:visited,
.the-cta-bottom a:link,
.the-cta-bottom a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #393939;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
  /*width: 100%;                                  not needed  */
  background: lightgreen
}

.the-cta {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-top: 30px;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;                /*  added  */
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<article id="wrap-a">
  <nav onclick="location.href='#';" class="the-cta">
    <span class="the-cta-top">some</span>
    <span class="the-cta-middle"><a href="#">text</a></span>
    <span class="the-cta-bottom">here</span>
  </nav>
  <!--
            -->
  <nav onclick="location.href='#';" class="the-cta">
    <span class="the-cta-top">more</span>
    <span class="the-cta-middle"><a href="#">text</a></span>
    <span class="the-cta-bottom">here</span>
  </nav>
</article>
```

---

Updated, with a version that will work from IE9.

Stack snippet

```css
#wrap-a {
}

.the-cta-top,
.the-cta-middle,
.the-cta-bottom {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.the-cta-top a:link,
.the-cta-top a:visited,
.the-cta-middle a:link,
.the-cta-middle a:visited,
.the-cta-bottom a:link,
.the-cta-bottom a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #393939;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
  background: lightgreen
}

.the-cta {
  display: inline-block;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 30px 0 0 calc( (100% - 300px) / 3);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.the-cta > span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

```html
<article id="wrap-a">
  <nav onclick="location.href='#';" class="the-cta">
    <span>
      <span class="the-cta-top">some</span>
      <span class="the-cta-middle"><a href="#">text</a></span>
      <span class="the-cta-bottom">here</span>
    </span>
  </nav><!--
  --><nav onclick="location.href='#';" class="the-cta">
    <span>
      <span class="the-cta-top">some</span>
      <span class="the-cta-middle"><a href="#">text</a></span>
      <span class="the-cta-bottom">here</span>
    </span>
  </nav>
</article>
```